# bash shell mysql command runs from command line but not inside script

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to get a bash script to delete a database. When I execute the command on the shell command line it works. When executed from the script I receive a response of:

> ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '-u' (0)

This is the command:

```
 mysql -h *server* -u *user* -p*pasword* -e "DROP *databaseName*";
```

Comment: It sounds like the server argument is empty when evaluated in the script. Perhaps show the shell script?

Comment: This is what happens when `mysql -h $host -u $user` evaluates to `mysql -h -u`. You can often expose this problem by using long-form arguments: `--host=$host --user=$user` and so on.

Comment: @IronMan Good catch. The command actually used some env variables for the -h, -u, and -p parameters. I could echo them in the shell but when echoed from the script they are empty.  Thanks.

Comment: Are the env variables being set from the same instance of the shell that the script is being run in? If so you need to make sure you `export` them.

Comment: Also, put double-quotes around all variable references (e.g. `mysql -h "$host" -u "$user"`). This avoids a lot of possible parsing weirdness. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, another tool for the box

Comment: @IronMan If you want to post as answer I'll credit you.

Comment: @lurker The "export" tip also solved another problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend checking first if the variable is set then use the variables, if not then better to use some default value to avoid such error like here `host` is not set.

```
mysql -h $([ ! -z "$host" ] || echo "localhost") -u $([ ! -z "$user" ] || echo "somedefault_user") -p$([ ! -z "$password" ] || echo "somedefault_pass")
```

You can also check in your bash script before connecting to mysql server.

```
if [ -z "$host" ]
then
      echo "\$host is empty, failed to connect mysql"
else
      echo "\$host is NOT empty"
      # delete DB here
fi
```